uniqueConstraint and get_or_create not working?
I am trying to make a thread safe/concurrent aware create function for some moel, as I understood it the following should work:
@transaction.atomic
def create_new_request(self, request: Request):
    item_id = 1
    item = Item.objects.get(id=item_id)
    print("creating", request.user)
    purchase_request, request_created = PurchaseRequest.objects.select_for_update().get_or_create(
        requester=request.user,
        status="draft",
    )
    purchase_request.save()
    print("get or created: ", purchase_request.id, request_created)

Then I created a unique constraint in the meta (as only "drafts" have this constraint of a single draft per user)
class PurchaseRequest(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Original Purchaserequest"
        verbose_name_plural = "Original Purchaserequests"
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["requester", "status"], condition=Q(status="draft"), name="unique_draft_user"
            )
        ]

However the moment I sent multiple requests at once from the frontend (using promise.all to sent many simultaneously), I notice that the application crashes with the following errors:
creating paulweijtens
creating paulweijtens
creating paulweijtens
get or created:  483 True
2024-12-08 22:21:27,732 ERROR root  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_draft_user"
DETAIL:  Key (requester_id, status)=(224, draft) already exists.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 916, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**kwargs), False
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "", line 637, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
isp.procure.purchase.models.PurchaseRequest.DoesNotExist: PurchaseRequest matching query does not exist.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_draft_user"
DETAIL:  Key (requester_id, status)=(224, draft) already exists.

What is happening here? First the handler says the get doesn't exist, and the it "does". I guess this is due to the race condition of 3 requests at the exact same time, however what is the solution?
As shown I already made the function atomic, and I already made the line lock by select_for_update()

Hmm, what version of Django are you using? Do you also run delete queries simultaneously with these queries (I don't really think you'll get this error without a concurrent delete with the recent versions of Django)?

This is django verion 4.2

Why particularly do you even want locking here? Can you try without the select_for_update, does it work when you do that? get_or_create is concurrency safe as long as you have the unique constraints set up properly.

I have tried without select_for_update, but I do notice that django does not properly lock anything. Even though as shown the unique constraint is in place (hence the error warnings).

No I am asking you to try without select_for_update since you don't really need a lock with get_or_create because the unique constraint would prevent any duplicate insertions.

Wait so you get the error for the unique constraint even without the select_for_update? Do your concurrent requests involve deletions of this object?

No it's literary the function multiple times (in javascript frontend we have a command that sends 10 times the request to create a request at once, using Promise.allSettled().  The remaining code is some slow code that creates more objects. I've also tried to wrap those in a separate action.

You are not selecting any rows to lock them.
You are trying to put lock on the new row (the one you just created) and other transactions are not trying to access it so lock is ignored.
You need to put lock on related model. In this case it will be User model from request.user.
Try something like this:
@transaction.atomic
def create_new_request(self, request: Request):

    user = User.objects.select_for_update().get(id=request.user.id)
    purchase_request, request_created = PurchaseRequest.objects.get_or_create(
        requester=user,
        status="draft",
    )
    print("get or created: ", purchase_request.id, request_created)

Now when other request tries to create new PurchaseRequest it will try to access user first, but there is lock on it so it will wait until previous transaction is over and lock is released

This technique unnecessarily locks the user model and will cause other requests that access the user instance to face issues. get_or_create ideally needs no locks.

While it would work: locking the user is a big no no. We only need to lock this specific insertion. and even just this function itself would be enough.
